# XML to Python Class to C Struct

Tags: python, struct, bit-fields

I need some advice. Two questions, does something already exist for this, what modules should I use to develop this.

I have some structures that come from an XML file. I want to represent them in Python Classes (maybe using a factory to create a class per structure). But I want these classes to have a function that will emit the structure as a C Struct.

From my research ctypes seems like the recommended thing to use to represent the structures in Python classes, but I don't see any methods for anything that will emit C Stucts for the creation of a header file.

Comment: Is this data directly related to the C structs you want to emit? Like it's a set of struct definitions in XML? Or is it real world data you want analyze and use to create struct definitions based on some analysis of your own?

Comment: They are register definitions for some HW. I want C Structs that mirror the HW and I want Python Classes the have the same field names etc.

Comment: 1. Could you give a context? 2. Do you only want to generate the source code? 3. Can you show example XML, Python, C?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but closely related: convert XML known structure (in the example, android-localiztion files) into C structures - see https://github.com/E-Brons/localization_xml_to_c

Answer (score 3):

From OP's comment I think the minimal solution a set of helper functions instead of classes.  the [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) library makes it easy to turn the XML data into nested dictionaries, more or less like JSON.  A set of helpers that parse the contents and generate appropriate C-struct strings is all that's really needed.  If you can work with dictionaries :

```
 {  
    "name": "my_struct",
    "members": {
                  [
                    "name":  "intmember", 
                    "ctype": "int"
                   },
                  {
                    "name":  "floatmember", 
                    "ctype": "float"
                   }
                 ]                 
 }
```

You can do something like:

```
from string import Template
struct_template_string = '''
typedef  $structname struct {
$defs
} $structname;
'''
struct_template = Template(struct_template_string)
member_template = Template("    $ctype  $name;")

def spec_to_struct(spec_dict):
    structname = spec_dict['name']
    member_data = spec_dict['members']
    members = [member_template.substitute(d) for d in member_data]
    return struct_template.substitute(structname = structname, defs = "\n".join(members))
```

Which will produce something like:

```
typedef  my_struct struct {
   int  intmember;
   float  floatmember;
} my_struct;
```

I'd try to get it working with basic functions first before trying to build up a class scaffold. It would be pretty easy to hide the details in a class using property descriptors:

```
class data_property(object):
    def __init__(self, path, wrapper = None):
        self.path = path
        self.wrapper = wrapper

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        result =  instance[self.path]
        if self.wrapper:
            if hasattr(result, '__iter__'):
                return [self.wrapper(**i) for i in result]
            return self.wrapper(**result)
        return result

class MemberWrapper(dict):
    name = data_property('name')
    type = data_property('ctype')

class StructWrapper(dict):

      name = data_property('name')
      members = data_property('members', MemberWrapper )


test = StructWrapper(**example)

print test.name
print test.members
for member in test.members:
    print member.type, member.name

# my_struct
# [{'name': 'intmember', 'ctype': 'int'}, {'name': 'floatmember', 'ctype': 'float'}]
# int intmember
# float floatmember
```